# QuiltView Gallery with Pull to Refresh in Android?

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh, quiltview

I am working on an social networking app in android where I was using **QuiltViewLibrary** for making a QuiltView Gallery of images.

In the same application I have used the **HANDMARKS Pull to Refresh library** for the GridView.

Both are working fine. Now I have to implement both the libraries for the combined task, that is PULL TO REFRESH in QuiltView GALLERY.

The problem which I am getting is to combine the XML of both the LIBRARIES which are totally different.

XML for PullToRefresh with simple GRID VIEW:

```
<!-- The PullToRefreshGridView replaces a standard GridView widget. -->
    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshGridView
        xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/pull_refresh_grid"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="fill"
        ptr:ptrMode="both"
        ptr:ptrDrawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

XML for QuiltView Gallery:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:quilt="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.tv.photos"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <com.tv.photos.QuiltView
        android:id="@+id/quilt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dip" >
    </com.tv.photos.QuiltView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Please let me know if anyone can suggest me something.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple:

- Chris Banes' pulltorfresh library supports `ScrollView`
- The QuiltView library is just an extension of a `GridLayout` (not GridView or any other adapter class)

Put an instance of `QuiltView` within an instance of `PullToRefreshScrollView`. Example [java](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/sample/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/samples/PullToRefreshScrollViewActivity.java), [xml](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/sample/res/layout/activity_ptr_scrollview.xml).

Shouldn't be any more complicated than this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView
        xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/pull_refresh_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <com.tv.photos.QuiltView
            android:id="@+id/quilt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dip" />

    </com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to use handmark's pulltorefresh library and create a pulltorefresh view that works with quiltview inside it.
Since QuiltView extends FrameLayout, you cannot use it directly in handmark's pull to refresh, but you have 3 options in front of you:

**1. Create new class of PullToRefreshQuiltView by extending PullToRefreshBase class.**

Just create a class extending PullToRefreshBase
You can check PullToRefreshWebView class to get an idea of how to do that.

**2. Use the scrollview in QuiltView's setup function**

[See line 50 of this link](https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary/blob/master/src/com/jake/quiltview/QuiltView.java)
You can either change the scrollview in setup function to a pullToRefreshScrollView, or add this scrollView to a ptr view.

**3. Use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager inside Handmark's PullToRefresh or android SwipeRefreshLayout**

The other option is to use a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager ( Something that looks like [GridLayoutManager Span Size RecycleView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511700/gridlayoutmanager-span-size-recycleview) ) inside handmark's pulltorefresh or android's SwipeRefreshLayout.

For more information about SwipeRefreshLayout check the android docs.