# Android Quilt LayoutManager

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager, quiltview

I was wondering whether there is a layout manager which can provide a grid/quilt recycler-view with different items widths and heights which looks like quilt view (the picture below)

[image: QuiltView picture]

[The QuiltView Library on GitHub](https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary)

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Budius, I found the following link that provides a view which looks similar to what I need but isn't exactly a quiltview:

[GridLayoutManager Span Size RecycleView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511700/gridlayoutmanager-span-size-recycleview)

Comment: Short answer. No. A bit longer answer: you can get somewhat similar results using either the `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` or a `GridLaytouManager` with an appropriate `SpanSizeLookup`

Comment: @Budius, Thanks, I updated my post based on your suggestion.